# Android Studio - language of string reference folding

Tags: android-studio

I like how the Android Studio folds R.string references into actual resource value. But is it possible  to change the language that is used for resource value retrieval? I was able to find only one setting - if it should be folded by default or not. (Editor->General->Code Folding)